# Is there a way to eliminate an extraneous index from this sum?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Fix a natural number $n$.  Suppose we have a triple sum of the form
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=j+1}^{i-1} f(i,k) $$
where the summands only depend on $i$ and $k$.

Is there a way to rewrite the sum so that it does not include the index $j$?

Comment: This page has seen some serious erasing of comments, hasn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sum can be written as
$$
\sum_{1 \le j < k < i \le n} f(i,k)
$$
(do you see why?)
From this form, it should be clear that for fixed $i,k$ the term $f(i,k)$ appears $k - 1$ times in the sum.  So you can write the sum as
$$
\sum_{2 \le k < i \le n} (k - 1) f(i,k).
$$
In general, a very helpful approach to multiple nested sums is to write them as a single sum over some inequality in the variables, as I have done above.

Comment: The "general" advice formulated in the last sentence of the post is correct.

Comment: Great!  This is very helpful.